# Discuss the continuabilty and differentiability

Tags: calculus

> $$f(x)=x e^{-(\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{1}{x})} \text{ for }x\not=0$$
>   $$ =0 \text{ for } x=0$$

I think it is$$\color{blue}{\text{ continuous and  differentiable at }x=0}$$
with$$\color{red}{\text{ left hand limit and right hand limit }=0}$$ and $$\color{green}{\text{ left hand derivative and right hand derivative }=1 }$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$

If $x>0$ then $|x|=x$

> $$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x e^{-(\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{1}{x})}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{xe^{-0}}{x}=1$$
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x e^{-(\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{1}{x})}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{-(\frac{2}{x})}=0$$

Thus $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

It is continuous though on all $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

It is continuous,

But not differentiable
[image]
You must have made some mistake